# for i,j in listname.iteritems(): is not working

Tags: python, iteration

the code below is a piece of a pokemon knockoff I'm coding, and the pokemon in the lists are all instances of a class.  The script throws no errors, but no matter what I type, it goes to the else statement "that's not a pokemon" and calls `player1_select()`...

```
pokemon_dict = {"joe":joe,"alex":alex,"ginger beard man":ginger_beard_man,"mark":mark}
pokemon_list = ["joe","alex","mark","ginger beard man"]
def player1_select():
    print pokemon_list
    response = raw_input("trainer 2 wants to battle!  which pokemon do you choose!?")
    for i,j in pokemon_dict.iteritems():
        if response == i:
            print "player1 selected " + i + "!"  
            p1 = j
            player2_select(p1)
        else:
            print "That's not a pokemon! yet..."
            player1_select()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing each and every element in the dictionary, which means that *all but zero or one* are not going to match. For all those that don't match the `else` branch is executed.

However, you have a dictionary; don't loop, just look up the entry directly in the mapping:

```
response = raw_input("trainer 2 wants to battle!  which pokemon do you choose!?")
if response in pokemon_dict:
    print "player1 selected " + response + "!"  
    p1 = pokemon_dict[response]
    player2_select(p1)
else:
    print "That's not a pokemon! yet..."
    player1_select()
```

`response in pokemon_dict` is True if there is a matching key.

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating through every key/value pair in the dictionary, in an arbitrary order. If the first one you check is not what the user input, the `else` block will be executed. You might have wanted something like:

```
if response in pokemon_dict: # Checks if `response` is a key in the dictionary
    print "player1 selected " + i + "!"
    p1 = pokemon_dict[response]
    player2_select(p1)
else:
    print "That's not a pokemon! yet..."
    player1_select()
```